# Find relation between sum of square roots?

Tags: inequality, radicals

> If $x=\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{20}$, $y=\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{17}$ and $z=\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{18}$, then which of the following holds true?
>
> - A. x < y < z
> - B. y < z < x
> - C. y < x < z
> - D. x < z < y
> - E. None of these

Please can anyone tell me how to solve this problem in Aptitude point of view

Comment: What is Aptitude point of view?

Comment: Means i need tricks to solve such question in less than a minute because I am preparing for aptitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2=31+2\sqrt{220}$

$y^2=32+2\sqrt{255}$

$z^2=32+2\sqrt{252}$

Comment: how to find relation now from this?

Comment: @KARTIKAGARWAL You're preparing for an aptitude test. You shouldn't need any hint for this part.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x<\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{20}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ is concave.

By the majorization inequality, we get $x<z<y$.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail

Comment: Basically, note that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, in the sense that $f''(x)<0$ everywhere in the domain. Thus for all $a>0$ if $a>b>c>0$ then $\sqrt{a-b}+\sqrt{a+b}<\sqrt{a-c}+\sqrt{a+c}$. In your problem I use $a=16$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality.